# Sales force refresh token could not generating in Laravel php

Tags: laravel, salesforce

hope you all are doing well. I am stuck with an issue since couple of hours and could not be able to resolve it. Please have a look on error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caqO4.png)

I am trying to generate refresh token. Access_token generated successfully that is expired after 20 minutes. refresh token could not be generated

```
  $client = new Client();
        $res = $client
        ->request("POST",
            "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",[
                'body'=> json_encode([
                    'grant_type'=>'refresh_token',
                    'client_id'=>Config::get('forrest.info.client_id'),
                    'client_secret'=>Config::get('forrest.info.client_secret'),
                   
                    'Authorization'=>'Bearer 00D3H0000008olE!ARYAQOzGGJDDIaygn7GokNk4T319XlDwwBXIDYPkJfej74dfhFT3CMDvBD2pZBQK_x.v2amiRe5Y29ZNXMp9EOA6ZTYyqrTW',
                    'access_token'=>'00D3H0000008olE!ARYAQOzGGJDDIaygn7GokNk4T319XlDwwBXIDYPkJfej74dfhFT3CMDvBD2pZBQK_x.v2amiRe5Y29ZNXMp9EOA6ZTYyqrTW',
                    
                ])
            ]
        );
        dd ($res->getStatusCode());
```

any help or comment would be highly appreciated! thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this error is returned from SalesForce API.
Looking at their documentation, it seems that they expect to see application/x-www-form-urlencoded not json.
Try out this code:

```php
    $client = new Client();
    
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/post', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token', 
            'client_id' => Config::get('forrest.info.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => Config::get('forrest.info.client_secret'),
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer 00D3H0000008olE!ARYAQOzGGJDDIaygn7GokNk4T319XlDwwBXIDYPkJfej74dfhFT3CMDvBD2pZBQK_x.v2amiRe5Y29ZNXMp9EOA6ZTYyqrTW',
            'access_token' => '00D3H0000008olE!ARYAQOzGGJDDIaygn7GokNk4T319XlDwwBXIDYPkJfej74dfhFT3CMDvBD2pZBQK_x.v2amiRe5Y29ZNXMp9EOA6ZTYyqrTW',
        ],
    ]);
    
    dd($response);
```

let me know if it helped.

Comment: No. My issue was that SalesForce would not generate Refresh Token. Access token will expire after 20 minutes and a New Access token would be generated as we do in very first step. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but too long for a comment)

This looks weird. "Authorization Bearer" should be a http header, not part of the message's body. Are you able to do what you need in plain old Postman, SoapUI etc?

Which OAuth2 flow did you use to generate this access token? Not all flows generate refresh token, for example https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5 says "this flow doesn't support scopes" so you get full access - but also "this response doesn’t send a refresh token."

Have you checked the connected app (place in SF where you took client id and secret from), do the OAuth2 scopes include refresh? Did you ask for refresh token (included it in the original request's grants)?